# How to show label or textbox made by coding in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

Let me explain how my program will be :

1.I have a textbox1 where the user will input a number
2.I have a button1,where it will it store the number from textbox1 into int Max

Here's the coding

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Max = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        fun = new TextBox[Max];
        for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                y = y + 26;
            }
            fun[i] = new TextBox();
            fun[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, y);
            fun[i].Text = "Test";
        }
    }
```

Now the only problem is it won't appear at all,because I don't know what code to make it appear on the form itself.

Comment: the control has to be added to page, or at any other runat server container element

Answer (score 1):

You need to Add the `TextBox` controls `fun[i]` (created at runtime) on the Form using `Controls.Add()` method.

Try This:

```
this.Controls.Add(fun[i]);
```

**Complete Code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Max = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        fun = new TextBox[Max];
        for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                y = y + 26;
            }
            fun[i] = new TextBox();
            fun[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, y);
            fun[i].Text = "Test";
            this.Controls.Add(fun[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where should I add it?at the button coding or outside it?

Comment: @user3756720: you need to addit immediatly after `fun[i].Text = "Test";` statement in forloop, check my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to dynamically create controls and display it in form? Looks like your code is okay, you need to add the controls to the Form to display it in the form. This code may help you.

```
int y = 26;
var Max = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
var fun = new TextBox[Max];
for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        y += 26;
    }
    fun[i] = new TextBox();
    fun[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, y);
    fun[i].Text = "Test";

    Controls.Add(fun[i]);
}
```